Is there a way to change the background color of combo-box picklist values
I have a lightning-combobox to display picklist values , but these values are coming with blue background when hovering around. Can we change this highlighted background color on the picklist dropdown from blue to any other color?

I used below, but it changes only the border color and not the background color. Any other styling hook to change background color?
:host .classType {
--lwc-shadowButtonFocus: 0 0 3px #d782ae ;
}

